# I have trouble understanding indexed family

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Define $f:\!R → \!R$ by $f(x) = cos(2x)$.
a) $f(\{\frac{-\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{2}\})$

ANS: $\{-0.5, 1\}$

b) $f([0, \frac{\pi}{4}])$

ANS: $[0, 1]$

c) $f(\!R)$

ANS: $[-1, 1]$

d) $f^{-1}(\{0\})$

ANS: $\{\frac{\pi}{8}\}$

e)$f(\cup_{n \in \!Z} [4n, 4n + 3])$

ANS: ???

I really have trouble with the last question, and my effort:

ANS: $[4, 7]$, but I am pretty sure I am wrong, how to understand the concept of family index?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f\left([0,\pi/4]\right)=\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right]\tag{b}$$

$$f^{-1}(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi;\;\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{d}$$

For question e) remember that $f(x)$ is periodic with period $\pi$

$$f([0,3]=[-1,1]$$

as you can see from the graph below the interval $[-1,1]$ is already covered when $0\le x\le \pi/2$.

BTW, the union in question e) is simply $$\ldots\cup[-8,-5]\cup [-4,-1]\cup[0,3]\cup[4,7]\ldots$$

---

[image]